# Android App Linking not working inside the WebView

Tags: android

[image: Android error - webpage not available]

When I try with the phone browser it opens the app. but not inside of the app webview.

```
public class WebViewPayNowFragment extends Fragment implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {
private View rootView;
private AdvancedWebView mWebView;
private String link, tid;

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        System.out.println("asdajsda : "+url);
        if (url != null && url.startsWith("ptcl://")) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
public WebViewPayNowFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        link = bundle.getString(Constants.LINK, null);
        tid = bundle.getString(Constants.TRANSACTION_ID, null);
        System.out.println("asdiahsdhakjshdkah : " + link);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false);
    mWebView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setListener(getActivity(), this);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    if (link != null) {
        String postData = null;
        try {
            postData = "TransactionID=" + URLEncoder.encode(tid, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mWebView.postUrl(link, postData.getBytes());
    } else {

    }

    return rootView;
}
```

Here is my code inside the fragment.
I created a inner class extending WebViewClient. and set the setWebViewClient but im still having the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

I encountered this situation myself. This is what I did:

First create a inner class and extend it with `WebViewClient`:

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    ....

    }
}
```

then:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url != null && url.startsWith("ptcl://")) {
        view.getContext().startActivity(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Lastly,

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
```

Try it, Hope it helps.

Comment: @Nuke You must create a class which extends `WebViewClient` then that method automatically comes. Just add those lines. Then add this `webView.setWebViewClient(your_class_object);`

Comment: Im using web view inside a fragment. it already extended with Fragment

Comment: You need to create an inner class. @Nuke See my edited answer.

Comment: I created a inner class and it Override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.
and then i webView.setWebViewClient to the webview.
is that all?

Comment: @Nuke Yes.. Don't forget to add INTERNET permission in your manifest.

Comment: i edited my question can you check and see what i missed there?

Comment: @Nuke Did you add internet permission?

Comment: yes. and i can open app using html link. and other internet related things also working.

Comment: @Nuke Write your entire link here: `if (url != null && url.startsWith("ptcl://")) {`